# Creating objects in Go

Tags: go

I'm playing around with Go for the first time. Consider this example.

```
type Foo struct {
    Id int
}

func createFoo(id int) Foo {
    return Foo{id}
}
```

This is perfectly fine for small objects, but how to **create factory function for big objects**?

In that case it's better to return pointer to avoid copying large chunks of data.

```
// now Foo has a lot of fields
func createFoo(id int /* other data here */) *Foo {
    x := doSomeCalc()
    return &Foo{
               Id: id
              //X: x and other data
   }
}
```

or

```
func createFoo(id int /* other data here */) *Foo {
    x := doSomeCalc()
    f := new(Foo)
    f.Id = id
    //f.X = x and other data
    return f
}
```

What's the difference between these two? What's the canonical way of doing it?

Comment: It's often a matter of opinion and style. There is no canonical form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The convention is to write `NewFoo` functions to create and initialize objects. Examples:

- [`xml.NewDecoder`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewDecoder)
- [`http.NewRequest`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequest)

You can always return pointers if you like since there is no syntactic difference when accessing methods or attributes. I would even go as far and say that it is often more convenient to return pointers so that you can use pointer receiver methods directly on the returned object. Imagine a base like this:

```
type Foo struct{}
func (f *Foo) M1() {}
```

When returning the object you cannot do this, since the returned value is not addressable ([example on play](http://play.golang.org/p/X2SLqiXhlU)):

```
NewFoo().M1()
```

When returning a pointer, you can do this. ([example on play](http://play.golang.org/p/DyqPq9Aslz))

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. Sometimes one version is the "natural one", sometimes the other. Most gophers would prefere the first variant (unless the second has some advantages).

(Nitpick: `Foo{id}` is bad practice. Use `Foo{Id: id}` instead.)

Comment: Another nitpick is that it's idiomatic to call such methods ``NewFoo``, or just ``New`` if your package is called ``foo``.